# Issues with deletion of Leads During Lead to member Conversion

Tags: apex, lead-conversion

While executing the class ‘LeadtoMember’, I am facing the the following issue. The delete code is outside the Trigger.new loop, but still i am getting the the error message, which i am not understanding.  Pls let me know your thought.

Trigger:

```
trigger LeadConversion on Lead (before update){
    List<Lead> leads= new List<Lead>();
    Set<Id> leadDeleteSet = new Set<Id>();
    for(Lead l:Trigger.new){
        if(l.Status != Trigger.oldMap.get(l.Id).Status && l.Status == 'Member'){
            leads.add(l);
            leadDeleteSet.add(l.Id);
        }
    }
    LeadtoMemberConversn lmc= new LeadtoMemberConversn(leads); 
    lmc.conversion();
    if (leadDeleteSet.Size() > 0){
           lmc.deleteLead(leadDeleteSet);
        }

    System.debug('values'+ lmc.getMembers());

}
```

Class:

```
public class LeadtoMemberConversn {
    List<Lead>  leads;
    List<Member__c> members;

    public LeadtoMemberConversn(List<Lead> leadList){
        leads=leadList;
        members= new List <Member__c>();
    }
    public void conversion(){
        for(Lead l: leads){
            Member__c member = new member__c();
            member.Name = l.FirstName +'' +l.LastName;            
            member.Email__c = l.Email;
            members.add(member);
        }
        insert members;
    }

     public void deleteLead(Set<Id>leadId){
           list<Lead> leadDeleteList = new List<Lead>();
           leadDeleteList = [SELECT Id from Lead where Id IN: leadId];
           delete leadDeleteList;
        }
    public List<Member__c> getMembers(){
        return members;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: error: Invalid Data.
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger LeadConversion caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: LeadConversion: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00Q9000000pcL9lEAE; first error: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER, Object (id = 00Q9000000pcL9l) is currently in trigger LeadConversion, therefore it cannot recursively delete itself: []: Class.LeadtoMemberConversn.deleteLead: line 22, column 1
 * = Required InformationLead Information